# Pasting inside delimiters without using visual selection

Tags: vim

In Vim, let's say I want to replace the contents of one String with the content of another.

**Original input**

```
var1 = "January"
var2 = "February"
```

**Desired output**

```
var1 = "January"
var2 = "January"
```

What I would usually do is:

- Move cursor to line 1
- `y` `i` `"` (yank inner quotes)
- Move cursor to the destination quote in line 2
- `v` `i` `"` `p` (visual select inner quotes, paste)

While this works well, I generally try to avoid visual mode when possible, so I am not completely satisfied with my step 4 (`v` `i` `"` `p`).

Is there any way to specify a "destination paste area" without using Visual mode? I suspect it might be something chained to `g`, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: "I generally try to avoid visual mode when possible" ... if you don't mind me asking, why?

Comment: Changing text with operator-motion is preferable to Visual mode because only the former can be repeated reliably with `.`. Drew Neil has called this the 'dot formula'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of doing this however using visual mode is the easiest.

- Use the black hole register to delete the content then paste. e.g. `"_di"P`
- Do `ci"<c-r>0`. `<c-r>` inserts the contents of a register
- Simply paste and then move over a character and delete the old text. e.g `pldt"`

However visual mode still has my vote. I find that the concerns most people have is that using visual mode + paste is that the default register is swap with the selected text and it doesn't repeat well. Good news everybody! The `0` register always stores the last yank. The bad news is visual mode still doesn't repeat well. Take a look at this vimcast episode, [Pasting from Visual mode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/pasting-from-visual-mode/), for more information. It mentions a few plugin that help with this.

Comment: For the second method, I think you should either use the black-hole register as in the first method (`"_ci"<c-r>"<Esc>`) or use the 0 register (`ci"<c-r>0<Esc>`).  For the third method, you have to start on the opening quote, not inside, and it will not satisfy the goal of being repeatable with `.` (nor will the first method).  I guess that goal was added (in the comments) after @PeterRincker's answer.

Comment: @benjifisher thank you. I have corrected the second option. I think if repeat-ability via `.` is the ultimate goal then the second method is probably best vanilla vim option. However using a plugin like Ingo Karkat's [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703), which is mentioned in the Vimcast episode, is probably the all around easiest solution for maintaining `.`'s repeat-ability.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly pretty, but here goes:

1. Go to line one and `yi"`
2. Move to line two
3. Type `"_di"hp`

That deletes what's in the quotes, but sends the deleted text to a black hole register. Then it moves the cursor back one, and pastes what you yanked from line one.

All in all, you can start on the first line and type `yi"j"_di"hp`. Why is it that people find vim intimidating? ;)

Alternatively, yank the first line as normal, then drop to line two and type `ci"<Ctrl+p>` and select the previously yanked text from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from my .vimrc:

```
" Delete to 'black hole' register
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
vnoremap <leader>d "_d
```

So, you just need to `\di"P` as your last step (assuming you use `\` as a `<leader>`).

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that addresses this problem precisely. It was presumably born out of the same feeling you're feeling, namely that Visual mode often feels less than ideal to advanced Vim users.

> [***operator-replace***](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-replace) – Operator to replace text with register content

With operator-replace installed the replacing goes like this.

1. Yank the word inside the quotes.

   ```
   yi"
   ```
2. Move to the target line

   ```
   j
   ```
3. Replace inside the quotes with the yanked text. (I've set up `gr` as the replace operator: `:map gr <Plug>(operator-replace)`. Pick your own mapping.)

   ```
   gri"
   ```

Check it out! This is part of the truly excellent [textobj](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user)/[operator](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) frameworks. I couldn't work without them.