# "paste inner", similar to "yank inner"

Tags: vim

Is there any known, straight-forward way to perform `inner <text-object>`-functons in Vim similar to yank-inner and delete-inner, only with paste? I know how to do this with Visual mode but it feels a few steps too long.

Example:

delete-inner (`di<text-object>`):

`user.name("Carl")` -> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> -> `user.name("")` + `Carl` is copied to clipboard.

Now, I occasionally find myself wanting to do something like this as well:

`user.name("")` -> <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> -> `user.name("Carl")`

I don't like taking the extra step inside Visual-mode, nor performing a
character/string-search (<kbd>/</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd>). Is there any way around this? Plugin-recommendations are also welcome if necessary.

Comment: I would do `vi"p` only one more keystroke than your `pi"`, without plugin/script/mapping.

Comment: That's what I do so far, I was just wondering if there was any way/plans of making Vim's pasting-fuctionality capable of acting upon text-objects.

Comment: Does `f"p` do what you want?

Comment: That's what I specified in the end of the post that I would preferably not use. It, along other solutions "works", but while the end-result is the same, the behaviour of the commands if different than the `verb`-inner methods.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. I'm also interested in finding the answer to this question.

Comment: No, there's AFAIK no plan to add such a feature. Making `p` an operator would break normal `pP` behavior so, maybe this could be emulated?

Comment: You've asked the same question before: [Pasting inside delimiters without using visual selection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22126784)

Comment: @glts Haha, and I gave the exact same answer back then! Hopefully, I'll get accepted again :-)

Comment: Well I'll be damned.. I knew there was something familiar about this issue. Proves it's not a corner-case then, at the very least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify (i.e. without the intermediate visual mode) and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

So, your example would be <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>.

**Edit:** Previous plugin versions didn't handle an empty text object well; fixed in the latest version 1.41.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

works for me, it pastes to the left instead of right which leaves it inside the quotes

assuming you want to change the value with the one on the clipboard

Alternately you can use `:map` to map pi" to either the command above or the Visual method keys